# Is there a difference between Microsoft Speech Platform Runtime 11 and Cortana's speech recognition?

Tags: c#, windows, speech-recognition, speech, cortana

I'm currently doing a research project on speech recognition systems, and I'd like to know if Microsoft Speech Runtime 11 and Cortana are different.
Cortana obviously is an assistant, but is the recognition of the voice the same for both systems?
I know cortana doesn't work on W7 and Speech Runtime does. So what is exactly the difference between the two.

Comment: looking forward for replies as i have also the same quest.

Answer (score 1):

The natural language processing capabilities of Cortana are derived from Tellme Networks (bought by Microsoft in 2007) and are coupled with a Semantic search database called Satori.

From what I can find online, they use different systems, with Speech Runtime 11 being developed by Microsoft, and Cortana's voice recognition being bought in.

Not a complete answer, as I can't find anything on the origins of Runtime 11, but hopefully that helps you in your search.

Comment: Yeah it does help a bit, but it's a shame there aren't any big articles about it. Atleast I got a direction now, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare Microsoft.Speech API vs Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition (Cortana)

- OS supported: Microsoft.Speech runs from Windows 7, 
  Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition  runs in Windows 10 only
- Setup: Microsoft.Speech has to be installed, Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition is already installed in Windows 10
- Supported languages: Microsoft.Speech supports more languages than Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition
- Acoustic Language model: Microsoft.Speech comes with a telephonic acoustic model, Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition has a deep neural network acoustic model at least 30% more accurate than Microsoft.Speech
- Offline usage: both work offline when you load a SRGS grammar
- Dictation: only Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition supports dictation, but in this case an internet connection is required
- Audio sources supported: Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition runs with a microphone only. Microsoft.Speech supports streaming and audio files

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Speech Runtime 11 does all the speech recognition on the client (the machine where MSR11 is installed).  Cortana does most of its speech recognition (and all of its language understanding) in the cloud.